How can we calculate entropy produced by plastic deformation in this example?
Suppose we have a massless spring of spring constant $k$ attached to a mass $m$ at equilibrium position $x_{0}$ at temperature $T$. The mass may oscillate in one dimension only for simplicity. We choose coordinates so that $x > x_{0}$ means the spring is stretched and $x < x_{0}$ means the spring is compressed. When the mass is at rest at position $x$, the total mechanical energy of the spring is
$$ E = \frac{1}{2}k(x-x_{0})^{2}. $$
Suppose we overstretch the spring to some position $x \gg x_{0}$, causing plastic deformation. I gather that this will shift the equilibrium position to some new value $x_{1} > x_{0}$. Then the total mechanical energy shifts:
$$ E = \frac{1}{2}k(x-x_{0})^{2}\rightarrow E' = \frac{1}{2}k(x-x_{1})^{2} < E. $$
(I'll assume $k$ is unchanged for the sake of simplifying the problem.)
Some mechanical energy was lost during the plastic deformation event, causing it to be lost to internal/thermal energy. If I'm not mistaken, this means entropy must have risen in this system. I am wondering if there is a systematic way to calculate this entropy change in the system. Any additional simplifying assumptions can be made as long as they are stated explicitly.
Comments:

If there are any wrong/nonsensical assumptions in this question/post, please point them out.
This example problem was thought up of by me. It was not posed by anything else.


I suggest get hold of this article Bridgman: The Thermodynamics of Plastic Deformation and Generalized Entropy https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.22.56 and study it, then come back with questions i.imgur.com/qQTH8Xx.png i.imgur.com/YfZHv0o.png i.imgur.com/PHxNVdO.png
i.imgur.com/s0anpxp.png i.imgur.com/rkO0Jaz.png i.imgur.com/31dTB0i.png
i.imgur.com/NL3IgXG.png i.imgur.com/7m6E76f.png
